# How to set a field to NULL in MySQL Query Browser?

Tags: mysql

I just decided to replace phpMyAdmin by Mysql Query Browser ( finally I can have tabs!! ), but I'm having a really stupid problem.
I need to set a field value to NULL instead of empty string: if I simply delete the content of the field, it will be set to empty string...

Of course, I don't want to do it through a query, I just want to use the visual editor.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the cell while not in edit mode and click "Clear field content"

Comment: That's almost it: if I'm currently editing the field, I can't do it. But if I right click on the cell while NOT editing it, it works. That's a bit weird, and it's the reason why I couldn't find it directly :)

Answer (score 2):

- Switch to `edit` mode
- Right click on `field`
- Choose "`Clear field content`"

Answer (score 0):

- Right Click - > `Edit Table Data`
- Right Click ON `Field`
- `Set Field(s) to NULL`  ( version 5.2.38 CE )

Or

- Just Type `NULL`
- And Press Enter

Comment: If you type "NULL", it will insert a string 'NULL' => not OK (on 5.2.38 CE, rev 8753)